# Filter pallet call by origin

Tags: runtime, call, origin, filter

Is there a way to access the call origin when using `BaseCallFilter` from
`frame_system::Config`?

Something like:

```rust
// Disallow any call to a given pallet
pub struct CallFilter;
impl frame_support::traits::Contains<RuntimeCall> for CallFilter {
    fn contains(c: &RuntimeCall) -> bool {
        match c {
            RuntimeCall::Balances(..) => /* validate origin */,
            _ => true,
        }
    }
}

impl frame_system::Config for Runtime {
    type BaseCallFilter = CallFilter;
    ...
}
```

I suspect it is not possible, and I will probably have to wrap `RuntimeOrigin`. But would appreciate if there is a better way to achieve what I described above.